# DNN upgrade - Portal.css not loading

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-9

We got a DNN website which was working on V.8.00.04 version. we upgraded this site from 8.00 to 9.01.01 version by following the steps mentioned in the DNN website. The upgrade was not too fast and we didn't see any issue while the upgrade was done. How ever, the site does not load any of the portal/css or portal/files. Basically the site loads without style sheet. I am seeing server 500 error for portal/files in the developer tools. Any help on how this can be fixed? thanks

Fix I tried:

1. I checked the portal folder and all the skins and styles are residing there
2. Changed the app pool to v.4.5 classic mode - no impact
3. Checked on the back-end for portal paths and everything looks clean

Comment: What exactly are the errors?

Comment: There should be error detail in the /Portals/_default/logs file if you can post them.  If you are using the Client Dependency Framework (Minified Files) increment the version number